# New TYPO3 installation on localhost: Backend does not work

Tags: xampp, typo3

I have installed a new copy of TYPO3 on localhost. When all the installation is finished I click to login and its giving error:

```
This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So the problem is that I'm unable to move to admin penal of TYPO3. I have installed many time new copy of TYPO3 but same error. I also have installed new xampp but same error. Can any one help me to solve this error?

Comment: If I get you right, you can access http://localhost/typo3/install.php and run all installation steps like entering the database credentials but you can not access http://localhost/typo3/index.php ?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 3):

Following steps will also sort this problem.

open httpd.conf file under xampp/apache/conf folder

add the following code if not there

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

save the file.

Now restart apache and then restart the XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an SSL problem with xampp default configuration.
To fix the Open SSL problem with Xampp under windows, you can download another version of Open SSL that works with TYPO3. You will find below the link to download the coresponding version of you 32 or 64 bits windows :
http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
– Win32 OpenSSL v1.x Light
or
– Win64 OpenSSL v1.x Light.

After installation, just copy/replace the two files below with the downloaded version:
– C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl\openssl.exe
– C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl\openssl.cfg

Restart Apache, then login on TYPO3 backend is ok!